# Serialize property of custom type as a string

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

There is a simple Product class. Pay attention to the `PriceCur` property the rest is unimportant:

```
public class Product
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Currency PriceCur { get; set; }
    public string ToXml()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new(typeof(Product));
        using MemoryStream stream = new();
        using StreamWriter writer = new(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        using XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true });
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, this);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

This is a Currency struct

```
    public struct Currency
    {
        static readonly Dictionary<string, string> currencies = new();
        static Currency()
        {
            currencies.Add("USD", "USD");
            currencies.Add("$", "USD");
            currencies.Add("&#36;", "USD");
            currencies.Add("EUR", "EUR");
            currencies.Add("€", "EUR");
            currencies.Add("&#8364;", "EUR");
        }
        public Currency(string currency)
        {
            Value = currencies.ContainsKey(currency) ? currencies[currency] : null;
        }

        public string? Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I serialize Product

```
    Product p = new()
    {
        Name = "Chocolate",
        Price = 5,
        PriceCur = new("$")
    };
    File.WriteAllText("product.xml", p.ToXml());
```

... and get XML like this:

```
<Product>
  <Name>Chocolate</Name>
  <Price>5</Price>
  <PriceCur>
    <Value>USD</Value>
  </PriceCur>
</Product>
```

What should I do to make nested tags PriceCur\Value\USD into just PriceCur\USD like this:

```
<Product>
  <Name>Chocolate</Name>
  <Price>5</Price>
  <PriceCur>USD</PriceCur>
</Product>
```

Comment: If it makes answer easier, I don't care about deserialization. I only need an XML.

Comment: I think the easiest answer is: define the property as `string PriceCur { get; set; }` and change the conversion logic to become a (static) helper method.